# Update list to tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to set a first item in my list of tuples, something like the first option in a select. I am trying the code below, but apparently is not a valid syntax.

There is any clean way to make this?

```
list_tuples = [('0', 'Choose'), (str(interest.id), interest) for interest in interests]
```

Comment: What is your input here? What is your expected output? Your description is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
list_tuples = [('0', 'Choose')] + [(str(interest.id), interest) for interest in interests]
```